# GridView: GridView is not updating

Tags: android, gridview

I have problem with updating `gridView` after delete some files. I've been searching the solution for a couple of days but still cannot solve the problem. The code is working fine, all thumbnails are viewed very smooth except when some files are deleted, there are no changes on `gridView`. Through some reading, `notifyDataSetChange()` must be used. But I'm not very clear how to use it and where to put it.

This is what I have:

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends Activity{
Cursor cursor;
private GridView mGridView;
ImageAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<ImageViewInfo> videoRows;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.images_layout);




String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID };

    String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE };

    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        mediaColumns, null, null, null);

    videoRows = new ArrayList<ImageViewInfo>();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {

        ImageViewInfo newVVI = new ImageViewInfo();
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        Cursor thumbCursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            thumbColumns, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                + "=" + id, null, null);
        if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
          newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
              .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
          Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
        }

        newVVI.filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        newVVI.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
        Log.v("", newVVI.title);
        newVVI.mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE));
        Log.v("", newVVI.mimeType);
        videoRows.add(newVVI);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, videoRows);
    mGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview5);
    mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);


mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {


        //Toast.makeText(ImageGridActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*
        if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
              int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
              int mimeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE);
              String videoFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
              String mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeColumn);
              Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);
              intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), mimeType);
              startActivity(intent);
            }
            */
        final CharSequence[] items = {
                "Open", "Upload","Delete", "Properties"
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageGridActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // Do something with the selection
                //mDoneButton.setText(items[item]);
                if(items[item].equals("Open"))
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                      int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                      int mimeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE);
                      String videoFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
                      String mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeColumn);
                      Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);
                      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), mimeType);
                      startActivity(intent);
                    }



                }
                else if(items[item].equals("Delete"))
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                          int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                          String videoFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
                          File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);                 
                          newFile.delete();
                        }
                        //ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(ImageGridActivity.this,videoRows);
                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mGridView.invalidateViews();
                        mGridView.setAdapter(null);

                    String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID };

                        String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE };

                        cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            mediaColumns, null, null, null);

                        ArrayList<ImageViewInfo> videoRows = new ArrayList<ImageViewInfo>();

                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                          do {

                            ImageViewInfo newVVI = new ImageViewInfo();
                            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
                            Cursor thumbCursor = managedQuery(
                                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                thumbColumns, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                                    + "=" + id, null, null);
                            if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                              newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                                  .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                              Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
                            }

                            newVVI.filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                            newVVI.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
                            Log.v("", newVVI.title);
                            newVVI.mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE));
                            Log.v("", newVVI.mimeType);
                            videoRows.add(newVVI);
                          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }

                        mGridView.invalidateViews();
                        mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ImageGridActivity.this,videoRows));


                }
                else if (items[item].equals("Properties"))
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                          int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                          //int fileSize = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE);
                          String filePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
                          //String fileSizes = cursor.getString(fileSize);
                        File newFile = new File(filePath);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageGridActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("File Details :");
                        builder.setMessage("Name: "+newFile.getName());
                        builder.setMessage("Path: "+filePath);
                        //builder.setMessage("Size: "+fileSizes);
                        builder.setCancelable(true);
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();

                        }                                           
                }               
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
});


}


class ImageViewInfo {
  String filePath;
  String mimeType;
  String thumbPath;
  String title;
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context context;
  private List<ImageViewInfo> videoItems;

  LayoutInflater inflater;

  public ImageAdapter(Context _context,
      ArrayList<ImageViewInfo> _items) {
    context = _context;
    videoItems = _items;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return videoItems.size();
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return videoItems.get(position);
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /*
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(95, 95));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        */

        //View videoRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        final ImageView videoThumb = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, parent, false);
        if (videoItems.get(position).thumbPath != null) {
          videoThumb.setImageURI(Uri
              .parse(videoItems.get(position).thumbPath));
        }
        else
        {
            videoThumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_empty);
        }



        /*
            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(videoItems.get(position).thumbPath));

        //Log.v("", "file://"+videoItems.get(position).thumbPath);
        //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://"+videoItems.get(position).filePath));
        */
        return videoThumb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the file from the imageList in the adapter. So that, the file path is remove from the list and it display only the image in a list.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;   
    }

    void add(String path){
        itemList.add(path); 
    }

    void remove(String path){
        itemList.remove(path);
    }
}

public void function_delete(int id){  
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
    }
    myImageAdapter.remove(path);
    myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}
```

Comment: wow! It's works like a charm. I really appreciate it. At last I can present this project to my lecturer. Thank for the help.

Comment: You are welcome dude..please vote the post if you really help this.